# What to do with XML Files generated by my Application

Tags: xml-serialization

I am making an application that persists several different user settings.  The way I have done it is just to serialize my collections (with the settings in them) to XML files.

As they are changed I update the saved file so that when the user runs again, the settings are saved.

As I get going with this style of persistence, I am finding that I have a lot of XML files.

Is this normal?  Is it ok to litter my installed directory with configuration xmls files?

Is there a way to hide these files?  Maybe a trick to save them as a resource under one file name?

This is not a really urgent issue.  It does not really bug me to have the XML files there, but I thought I would ask.

I am using C# and VS 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not at least put them in their own folder? "/App_Data" for example?  Beyond that... If you are getting a lot of files, what are the chances of being able to switch to a database? (SQLLite or something along those lines)